# 404 Using getServerSideProps in a Dynamic page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using `Next.js` 13, and below is my code for a dynamic page  `[id].jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    Sugestions,
    PosterContainer,
    LogoRates,
    DescriptioContainer,
    RatesContainer,
    Purple,
    ContainerInfoMovie,
    Poster,
    As,
    Info,
    Contenedor,
    Puntuaciones,
} from "@styles/pages.styles/movies.styles";
import Card from "@components/card/Card";
import Image from "next/image";
import { getMovie, getMovies } from "@/services/movies/movie.service";

function MovieDetail({ movies, cardMovies }) {
    return (
        <main>
            <Purple></Purple>
            <Contenedor>
                <ContainerInfoMovie>
                    <Info>
                        <p className="genero">{movies?.genre}</p>
                        <p className="anio">{movies?.releaseDate}</p>
                        <p className="titulo">{movies?.title}</p>
                        <span className="cast">
                            Director:
                            <p className="castD">{movies?.director}</p>
                        </span>
                        <span className="cast">
                            Musica:
                            <p className="castD">{movies?.composer}</p>
                        </span>
                        <span className="cast">
                            Elenco:
                            <p className="castD">{movies?.actors}</p>
                        </span>
                        <span className="platforms">
                            Disponible en:
                            <div className="imagenPlatform">
                                <Image className="logo" src="/images/home/logos/disney.svg" alt="" width={100} height={100} />
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </Info>
                    <As>
                        <PosterContainer>
                            <Poster src={movies?.image_url} />
                        </PosterContainer>
                        <RatesContainer>
                            <LogoRates src="/images/home/A.png" alt="Profile" />
                        </RatesContainer>
                        <div className="container">
                            <Image src="/images/home/Star1.png" alt="" width={40} height={40} />
                            <Image src="/images/home/Star1.png" alt="" width={40} height={40} />
                            <Image src="/images/home/Star1.png" alt="" width={40} height={40} />
                            <Image src="/images/home/Star1.png" alt="" width={40} height={40} />
                            <Image src="/images/home/Star1.png" alt="" width={40} height={40} />
                        </div>
                    </As>
                </ContainerInfoMovie>
                <DescriptioContainer>
                    <Puntuaciones className="puntuacion">
                        <p className="numerosPorcentaje div3">{movies.rt_score}</p>
                        <p className="numerosPorcentaje div4">{movies.imdb_score}</p>
                        <p className="numerosPorcentaje div5">{movies.mc_score}</p>

                        <Image src="/images/Group.svg" alt="imagen1" width={50} height={50} className="div6" />
                        <Image src="/images/Metacritic1.png" alt="imagen1" width={50} height={50} className="div7" />
                        <Image src="/images/RottenTomatoes.png" alt="imagen1" width={80} height={50} className="div8" />
                    </Puntuaciones>
                    <p className="day_p">{movies.review}</p>
                </DescriptioContainer>
                <Sugestions>
                    <h4 className="oldies_title">Sugerencias</h4>
                    <div className="suggestions_cards">
                        {cardMovies.slice(0, 3).map((item) => (
                            <div className="card" key={item.id}>
                                {" "}
                                <Card movie={item} />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </Sugestions>
            </Contenedor>
        </main>
    );
}

export default MovieDetail;
```

I'm using `getServerSideProps` in this page using:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(contexto) {
    const { id } = contexto.params;
    const movies = await getMovie(id);
    const cardMovies = await getMovies();

    return {
        props: {
            movies,
            cardMovies,
        },
    };
}
```

But I'm getting 404 when I try to use `getServerSideProps` in this page.

I tried to downgrade my Next.js version to 12, but it didn't work. I then to remove the SSR and that worked. But I need to get it working with SSR.